# accessing 'this' of an outer object (javascript)

Tags: javascript

how can i use `this` of obj in `sayHi()`

i want `this` in sayHi to refer to `this` in obj what changes should i add to sayHi so it prints harry potter instead of undefined

```
let obj = {
    fullName: "Harry Potter",
    person: {
        sayHi: function(){
            return "This person's name is " + this.fullName
        }
    }
}
```

is there another way than this `obj.person.sayHi.call(obj)` or `obj.person.sayHi.apply(obj)` to do it;

Comment: You could also use `bind` instead of `call`. It's a similar concept though: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: `var` inside function is private / local scope

Comment: you can always change the code to access `obj.fullName` if you don't want to use `call` or `apply`. `this` in this case points to `person`. Not sure if that's what you intend to do

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```js
var obj = {
    fullName: "Harry Potter",
    person: {
        sayHi: function(){
            return "This person's name is " + this.fullName
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj.person.sayHi.apply({fullName: 'John'}))
console.log(obj.person.sayHi.apply(obj))
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `sayHi()` function the `this` refers the `sayHi` function but not the object `obj`. So in this scenario you can bind the reference `this` using `.call()`

```js
var obj = {
    fullName: "Harry Potter",
    person: {
        sayHi: function() {
            return "This person's name is " + this.fullName
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj.person.sayHi.call(obj))
```

Comment: @DavinTryon  I think he meant to do -> `.bind(obj)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. `obj` contains a reference to the object in it's `person` property, the object however doesn't know were it is in, it could also be referenced at multiple places.

You could create a reference from `person` to `obj`:

```
obj.person.parent = obj;
```

Then you can access it as `this.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it, but I think it's more appropriate to use classes for this case.

```
class Person{
    constructor(fullName){
        this.fullName=fullName;
    }
    sayHi(){
        return "This person's name is " + this.fullName
    }
};
HP = new Person("Harry Potter");
HP.sayHi()
```

"This person's name is Harry Potter"

Comment: I wouldn't say `you need to use`.  But of course doesn't harm in doing so.. :)

Comment: This is not the same object from OP. Indeed, you can achieve the same, withou class. just rename obj as person and put `sayHi` in the same scope as `this.fullName`